# Is there any way to share images between two streamlit webapps?

Tags: python, heroku, image-processing, web-hosting, streamlit

I want to link 2 web pages made using streamlit and hosted using Heroku. One of them removes the image background and the other does an image classification task. (They could not be made into one due to slug size limits of Heroku). At present, the user has to manually download the segmented image from one webpage and upload it to the second webpage.

The 2 can be shown together using an HTML iframe tag but I am not able to figure out how to transfer the segmented image from one webpage to other.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated

Also please prefer solutions using python and its frameworks as the whole project is in python and learning javascript, HTTP, etc will take some time.

(but if it's not possible using python, answers using other methods will also be welcome)

Comment: You must include the code within the body of your question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Thanks for telling.Actually the code was not much relevant to the question so just removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my seniors advised me to explore other hosting options. (I had seen an online tutorial using Heroku , and did not know much about others). It turns out that streamlit cloud provides a much larger slug size and allows you to host it for free if you open source your project(I had no issue doing so), so I have combined the two parts and am now hosting using streamlit cloud.

Comment: how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did not get.Can you please tell specifically the mistake I made so that it can be rectified

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, on rereading I found there were many grammatical errors. Fixed.